# ssh: connect to host e121a0ef81ef(container id) port 22: Connection refused in docker

Tags: docker, hadoop, weave

I have three hosts with docker installed on each of them. I want to have a distributed file system,HDFS, among three container. So, I have to make a hadoop cluster. I use this docker file to make a hadoop image.

```
FROM ubuntu_mesos
ENV HADOOP_HOME /opt/hadoop
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh rsync vim openjdk-8-jdk
# download and extract hadoop, set JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh, update 
path
RUN wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop- 
3.1.0/hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz && tar -xzf hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz && \
mv hadoop-3.1.0 $HADOOP_HOME && \
echo "export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" >> $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
hadoop-env.sh && \
echo "PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin" >> ~/.bashrc
# create ssh keys
RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa && cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
>> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ADD core-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
ADD hdfs-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
ADD mapred-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
ADD mapred-site.xml $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/
ADD ssh_config /root/.ssh/config
COPY start-hadoop.sh start-hadoop.sh
EXPOSE 22 9000 8088 50070 50075 50030 50060
RUN echo export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="root" >> 
$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh 
RUN echo export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="root" >> 
$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
RUN echo export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="root" >> 
$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
RUN echo export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="root" >> 
$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
RUN echo export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="root" >> 
$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

After building the docker file. I sat up docker swarm on thee hosts. I installed **weave net** and made a container network like this:

```
docker plugin install weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release
docker network create --driver=weaveworks/net-plugin:latest_release 
--attachable mycontainernetwork
```

I connected three hosts with running this command on each host:

```
sudo weave launch <IP address of first host> <IP address of second 
host>
```

Then,I ran hadoop image with container network on each host like this:

```
 sudo docker run -it --net mycontainernetwork my-hadoop
```

I checked that each container could recognize other containers with running this command on each container:

```
 ping -c 1 -q ContainerID
```

But, when I want to run this command:

```
 ssh e121a0ef81ef
```

I receive this error:

> > ssh: connect to host e121a0ef81ef port 22: Connection refused

"e121a0ef81ef" is my container ID.

I am confused and do not know how to solve the problem. Would you please help me?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the `ssh` service running in your container?

Comment: @Thomasleveil, when I run "ssh start" on the container, I get this error: **Could not resolve hostname start: Temporary failure in name resolution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I did these stages:
First, I made ssh passwordless among three hosts. 
In three host:

```
 ssh-keygen
```

Then, for each slave, I ran this command in Master:

```
 ssh-copy-id user@ip
```

I tested that **ssh** works without password between Master and slaves. Therefore, I copied "~/.ssh" folder from host to container in each host. By the way, I entered to the container with this command:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/user/.ssh:/root/.ssh --net mycontainernetwork
 --privileged my-hadoop
```

I debugged ssh to understand the problem:

```
ssh -v user@ip
```

The most important points are that after entering to  the container, you have to restart ssh with this command:

```
  /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

or

```
  service ssh restart
```

Also, you must give privilege to **.ssh** folder with this command:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

After that I can run **ssh** command to remote container.

Hope it was helpful for others.